# JQUERY - add CSS class to BUTTON element after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change the background color of a button permanently after it is clicked. Using the following code the color only changes while the button is active/being clicked. Once the mouse button is released the added "clicked" class is no longer applied to the element.

Applying the following code to an INPUT tag instead of a BUTTON tag works the way I need it to. However, I'm using a BUTTON tag since I want the value to be different from the text inside the button.

What do I need to change?

-- Thanks.

```
 HTML
 <button class="inactive" value="test">Button</button>

 CSS
 .inactive {background-color:gray;}
 .clicked {background-color:orange;}

 JS
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $('button').click(function(){
           $(this).addClass('clicked');
      });
 );
```

Comment: I can't replicate your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/9AT48/

Comment: This works fine in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v6nCb/). My guess would be that you have other CSS which you've not included which is interfering with this jQuery.

Comment: I found the problem. The button tag was inside a form element and was submitting and reloading the page upon being clicked. I didn't realize buttons submitted by default. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7):

The only problem is that you are missing a curly brace: http://jsfiddle.net/AaKuf/

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $('button').click(function(){
           $(this).addClass('clicked');
      });
 }); //<==here
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('button.inactive').click(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('inactive').addClass('clicked');
});
```

Should do the trick. This will clear the old class away from the button and give it the proper `.clicked` class. If the colour is resetting after using this solution, then the problem is elsewhere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('button').mouseup(function() { 
    $(this).removeClass('clicked').addClass('inactive');
}
```