# Add css class on div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have the following html code and i want to add on click the class "rotate" (which i have included in my css) to the div with class "barklogo"

```
<div class="barklogo loaded" data-width="40" data-anim="left">
<img src="/images/home/button.png" border="0" alt="Demo image">
</div>
```

I found a similar post here

[JQUERY - add CSS class to BUTTON element after click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17092067/jquery-add-css-class-to-button-element-after-click)

But when i enter the following code to the js file it won't work

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('barklogo').click(function(){
       $(this).addClass('rotate');
  });
 });
```

Here is the css code for the class .rotate

```
.rotate{
transform: rotate(360deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
-o-transform: rotate(360deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `.` with class name in jquery.

```
 $('.barklogo').click(function(){
```

[Class Selector (“.class”)](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this:
Use `.` when u are using class selector

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.barklogo .loaded').click(function(){
       $(this).addClass('rotate');
  });
 });
```

Comment: Your selector is wrong. `$('.barklogo .loaded')` finds all elements that have class `loaded` that are descendants of an element that has class `barklogo`.

Answer (score 1):

You have missed to add `.` in selector,

```
    $(function(){
      $('.barklogo').click(function(){
           $(this).addClass('rotate');
      });
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed `.` for [class selector in jquery](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

Change `$('barklogo').click(function(){` to `$('.barklogo').click(function(){`

Answer (score 0):

Its really working by this way. But if u want in safe way to addClass which already have more than one class in div than use addClass to div by its ID. for example,

```
$("#div_id").click(function(){
    //code 
});
```

This is your useful way for this question.

```
<script>

$('.barklogo').click(function(){
           $(this).addClass('rotate');
      });

</script>
```